# When creating a sprite should I pull all the actual sizes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, images, css, sprite

I would like to know if i should put all the sizes that are going to be used in the web site in the sprite or if i should put only one and let the Front-end designer scale it with CSS but it seems weir to me to scale the whole image (sprite) only for one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an image(png, gif, etc) sprite, you have to put all the sizes that you use on your layout. Resizing the whole sprite to get to a desired size of an especific image on the sprite is not an option.

**Edit:**
Example of the problems that resizing the whole sprite in CSS can cause for the front-end dev.

[image]

The first sprite is the original size with 5 icons;
The second sprite is the resized version using CSS;

Then lets say that you had to edit the sprite to add 3 more icons, the original size of you sprite wont be 350 x 100.

**The problem:**
The third sprite, with the adition of those 3 icons, and making the canvas larger, the resized sprite will loose the size and position.